# Set session variable from SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I am trying to set some session variable from the return of a `SqlDataSource`. I am able to set the value to a label/textbox/hidden field, but I cannot seem to set the session variable.

I am using a `page_load` function to try and set them.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
        this.Session["UserName"] = User.Identity.Name;
        this.Session["EmplID"] = Eval("EmplID");
}
```

I have a `SqlDataSource`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLGetEmplID" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MAFapp %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT EmplID, Status FROM Employees WHERE (intLogin = @UserName) AND (Dept = N'Eng' OR Dept = N'IS') AND (Status = N'Active')">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter Name="UserName" SessionField="UserName" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: why would someone give a negative vote? is it a bad question? if so, then why?

Comment: quick question.. have you stepped thru the code..? where are you returning the rows of the selected EmplID from the User.Identity.Name ..?  I am curious to how you are parsing the User.Identity.Name can you show all relevant code also what does the name come back as .. is it for example `DomainName\Beebgie` is so then you need to Split the User.Identity.Name and return the value in array position[1] Do you use `PricnipalContext`

Comment: the User.Identity.Name is returning the login without the domain. Yes there is a label field that is accessing the EmplID from SQLGetEmplID but I am looking to remove that since there is no need for the user to have to what his/her ID. I am trying to fix a mess that was handed to me.

Comment: I have a simpler example if you want to try using PrincipalContext you can get at a lot of things you need to and or validate against.. I will post as an alternative example if you like

Comment: when you step thru the code put a breakpoint on `if(user` and you will see all the properties that `user` yields also I feel your pain when it comes to fixing someone else's `Mess` refactoring is always a good thing as as a way to learn newer things

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to what you are doing if your `User.Identity.Name`

```
string fullUserName = null;
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc,User.Identity.Name))
    {
        if (user != null)
        {
            fullUserName = user.DisplayName;//this can be what ever you like 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the code but got an error for the `PrincipalContext`. I did some research and saw that I needed to include the assembly reference `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. I added it, but I'm still getting an error `CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PrincipalContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Is this accessing the Windows login or is this still accessing the intranet login?

Comment: if this works for Both windows and Internet the difference is with internet you would get something like `domainname\username` then you would need to use the split function to get the string[] position of the 2nd element so in `C#` that would be someStringArray[1] for example.. have you tried it in a small `ConsoleApp` for example you will see what I mean.. let me know if that helps